# Routes registration in ASP MVC for a simple Library Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, controllers, clean-urls

I would like to create a web site using ASP MVC with the following URLs:

```
/libraries                      ## displays a list of libraries
/libraries?pageIndex=1          ## a list of libraries with pagination
/libraries/1                    ## the library with ID == 1
/libraries/1/books              ## a list of books in the library 1
/libraries/1/books?pageIndex=0  ## a paged list of books in the library 1
/libraries/1/books/2            ## the book with ID == 2 in the library 1
/libraries/1/books/2/edit       ## edit page for the book 2 in the library 1
```

What is the best way for the RouteCollections and Controllers registration?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have two routes with the following patterns:

`{controller}/{parentId}/{item}/{id}/{action}`

Where:

- `{action}` is optional and defaults to `index`;
- `{id}` is optional

`{controller}/{parentId}`

Where:

- `{parentId}` is optional

Your RouteConfig.cs file could look something like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "libraryDetail",
        url: "{controller}/{parentId}/{item}/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Libraries", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "libraries",
        url: "{controller}/{parentId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Libraries", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: yeah, I agree with two routes registration, but it would be better to make `Controller = Books` first with `URL = libraries/{libraryId}/{controller}/{id}/{action}` and then `Controller = Libraries` with not so strong `URL = {controller}/{id}/{action}`. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a great article that answers all my questions, hope it could be helpful for somebody else :)

[Customizing Routes in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC)